# Xamarin on OSX access web service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/connect-to-local-web-services) I can put 10.0.2.2:port in the host and access the webservice from my android emulator. This does not seem to apply if I am using a mac (OSX). Is there a different trick if you are using a mac ? Both the Android App and the webservice would be running on the mac. There is no windows machine.

Comment: are you running both the webservice AND the emulator on your mac?

Comment: Yes there is no PC involved. Its all running on the Mac(OSX)

Comment: Could you access it on browser (like safari) or postman?

Comment: on the mac yes but not in a browser in the emulator